# Function of .gitignore to avoid pushing of API keys?

Tags: git, config, gitignore

Hi I will be using MySQL Connector/Python to access some data in DB. I have read in the [guidelines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-coding.html) not to hardcode the keys on to the code but use `config.py`. I have also found that it can be done with [JSON](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/). My app will be served to Heroku. What's the use of .gitignore? On this [example](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/), he used the name `databaseconfig.py`. But added a line `*config.py` in the `.gitignore` file. Why is not `*databaseconfig.py`? Also what is the equivalent if I have to add the JSON config file to the .gitignore? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is using `*config.py` line in the `.gitignore` because then git will ignore every file which ends in `config.py`, for example `dabaseconfig.py`, `config.py`, `networkconfig.py` and `testingtestingothertestconfig.py` all get ignored (but for example `confignotcorrectformat.py` will **not** get ignored). The `*` is a so called wildcard and will match anything.

If you need to ignore a JSON config file you can use the line `*config.json` in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Hi! If I pushed this? Will these files included? I have to run it on Heroku, will my app be able to get these keys if its not pushed since it was .gitignore-ed?

Comment: I don't think Heroku needs your config files to be in git.